# Bootstrap SASS generates vendor folder

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-sass

I have set up Bootstrap SASS, everything works almost fine, except that compass generates a foloder vendor/bootstrap.css beside the styles.css file. This is weird because the bootstrap is already included in style.css. I couldn't find any configuration options in bootstrap variables.

Comment: sounds like it's a compass issue, not a bootstrap-sass issue.

Comment: yeah, but i don't know what could i've set up wrong.

Comment: I see now that if I remove the @import bootstrap from the main scss file, only the vendor/bootstrap.css file is generated. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to import the bootstrap file into another scss file, then you have to rename the bootstrap.scss to _bootstrap.scss.

Files starting with an underscore are not generated as css-file.